# VBA to click Excel's Format Painter and copy active cell?

Tags: excel

I use the `Format Painter` a lot and often it would be a bit faster to activate it with the keyboard instead of clicking the tool icon. I don't believe there is one built into `Excel 365` so I tried the trivial macro below. However, that and various other versions I tried all failed.

How do I simply click the `Format Painter` and copy the active cell, ready for pasting that format elsewhere?

```vb
Sub ClickFormatPainter()

' Select cell to copy then activate Format Painter, ready to paste elsewhere.
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+F

  ActiveCell.Address.Select
  Selection.Copy

End Sub
```

Comment: Feels over-engineering to do this. Wouldn't ctrl+alt+v -> t do the trick?

Comment: You could just add it to the start of the QAT and then use Alt+1

Comment: Thanks Rory, neat.